# How to check if id occurs in other table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table `an_visit` that has column `visit_id`. There is also a table `an_transaction` that has some `visit_id` too.

I would like to get a new column in MySQL based on if `visit_id` occurs in both tables. My approach:

```sql
SELECT visit_id, datetime_add, ISNULL((SELECT   
                1
                FROM an_transaction
                WHERE an_transaction.visit_id = an_visit.visit_id), 0)
  
            FROM an_visit
            WHERE datetime_add >= '2021-08-01'
            LIMIT 50
```

But I got this error: `MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1582, "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'")`. What do I do wrong, please?

Comment: `SELECT 1`, did you mean `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: isnull function only accepts 1 parameter see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT visit_id, datetime_add, ISNULL((SELECT   
                1
                FROM an_transaction
                WHERE an_transaction.visit_id = an_visit.visit_id limit 1))
  
            FROM an_visit
            WHERE datetime_add >= '2021-08-01'
            LIMIT 50
```

OR

```
SELECT visit_id, datetime_add, IFNULL((SELECT   
                1
                FROM an_transaction
                WHERE an_transaction.visit_id = an_visit.visit_id limit 1),0)
  
            FROM an_visit
            WHERE datetime_add >= '2021-08-01'
            LIMIT 50
```

Comment: the second solution is what I need, thanks a lot!